# SQL how to get only one result from each value

Tags: php, sql

I have this sql query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE `to_id` = '$user_id' AND `from_id`   IN($data)") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

that returns this arrays:

```
Array ( [id] => 3505 [from_id] => 111 [to_id] => 109 [message] =>How are you? [sent] =>          1343109753 [recd] => 1 [system_message] => no )    
Array ( [id] => 3506 [from_id] => 111 [to_id]   => 109 [message] =>well... [sent] =>   1343109759 [recd] => 1 [system_message] => no ) 
Array ( [id] => 3507 [from_id] => 141 [to_id] => 109 [message] => bye [sent] => 1343901524 [recd] => 1 [system_message] => no )
```

From_id is the user ID of the person sending the message but I would like to get only one (the most recent) result for each 'from_id'. (in this example I got 2 messages from the same 'from_id' - 111)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT * FROM chat WHERE `to_id` = '$user_id' AND `from_id` IN($data) GROUP BY  `from_id` ORDER BY `sent` DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM chat WHERE to_id = '$user_id' AND`from_id`IN($data) GROUP BY from_id order by sent desc`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
SELECT a.*
FROM chat a INNER JOIN
        (
           SELECT   from_id, to_id ,MAX(sent) maxSent
           FROM     chat
           GROUP BY from_id, to_id
        ) b ON a.from_id = b.from_id AND
                a.to_id = b.to_id AND
                a.sent = b.maxSent
WHERE `to_id` = '$user_id' AND 
        `from_id` IN ($data)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM chat WHERE to_id = '$user_id' AND from_id IN($data) order by sent desc limit 0,1

Order by will order the recent messgae and LIMIT 0,1 will return only one message.